# Using dask map_partition gets stuck in inifinite error loop

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-ec2, python-multiprocessing, dask

I'm trying to parallelize a function over a pandas dataframe with dask. On my local windows machine (python 3) i have no problems, but when i try running on my remote aws machine with ubuntu 16 and python 2 or 3 i get the following error:

dask version 0.16.1

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.multiprocessing import get

def process_frame(x):
            # extract and process wav files
            return process_wav_file(x)
            # or even return 0

dfdd = dd.from_pandas(existing_df, npartitions=4)
results = dfdd.map_partitions(lambda df: 
                              df.wav_file.apply(process_frame) ,meta=('x', 'f8')).compute(get=get)
```

wav_file column in the above code holds the path to wav files. The error i get is as follows and it keeps repeating like an infinite loop:

```
Process ForkPoolWorker-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/envs/cx/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/multiprocessing.py", line 192, in initialize_worker_process
    np.random.seed()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/envs/cx/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
Process ForkPoolWorker-2:
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/envs/cx/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/envs/cx/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 103, in worker
    initializer(*initargs)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/envs/cx/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
Process ForkPoolWorker-3:
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/envs/cx/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/envs/cx/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 103, in worker
    initializer(*initargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/envs/cx/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/multiprocessing.py", line 192, in initialize_worker_process
    np.random.seed()
Traceback (most recent call last):
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
Process ForkPoolWorker-4:
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/envs/cx/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/envs/cx/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/envs/cx/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 103, in worker
    initializer(*initargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/envs/cx/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/multiprocessing.py", line 192, in initialize_worker_process
    np.random.seed()
Traceback (most recent call last):
Process ForkPoolWorker-5:
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/envs/cx/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/envs/cx/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/envs/cx/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 103, in worker
    initializer(*initargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/envs/cx/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/multiprocessing.py", line 192, in initialize_worker_process
    np.random.seed()
Traceback (most recent call last):
Process ForkPoolWorker-6:
```

Comment: Have you tried running `process_wav_file` without `dask` on the remote machine? Would be useful to know what `process_wav_file` does

Comment: @MattiLyra let's just say it returns `0` i have tried this stab and also the actual one which returns an numpy.array. `process_wav_file` works by itself.